# Edit accepted by peers. Original answerer reverts it back

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

In question [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683442/where-can-i-find-the-clamp-function-in-net/2683487#2683487) q&a I edited the answer to improve its readability and remove the unneeded else clauses. After it being accepted by peer review the original answerer reverted it because he disagrees with the edit. I changed it again and after it being accepted he reverted again.

What is the proper thing to do in cases like these? Since the edit is accepted by reviewers my understanding is that it indeed improves the answer. But the answerer disagrees.

Comment: I don't see the point of making code formatting edits to a six-years-old answer. Much less changing the code.

Comment: _I changed it again:_ Don't do that. If the OP doesn't like your change, then you have to accept it.

Comment: [You re-suggested the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13586863), prior to making this post. This time, it'll be rejected, [as it should](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333959/1743880).

Comment: "Since the edit is accepted by reviewers my understanding is that it indeed improves the answer." Unfortunately, no. We have quite a few robo-reviewers who will happily approve everything they encounter. It's sad, but you cannot trust the judgment of the reviewers.

Comment: popularity is not a valid indicator of correctness as your edit proves, your edit actually is **worse** practice, you should never have fall through `if` blocks, it is just creating an implicit statemachine. An `if/elseif/else` as it was is the most correct and explicit way to say `this/or this/else default to this` without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the proper thing to do in cases like these?

Move on.

> Since the edit is accepted by reviewers my understanding is that it indeed improves the answer. But the answerer disagrees.

So? It's his answer. Your change was nothing more than formatting. If the answerer doesn't like that formatting, that's their right.

Answer (score 16):

You made an entirely inappropriate edit that should never have been approved in the first place; two of the reviewers correctly rejected it, but three of them inappropriately approved it..  That the original author reverted it is perfectly fine.

You should not be editing other people's code to change it from their stylistic preferences to yours.  There was nothing wrong with the code in that answer.  That it doesn't fit your personal preferences doesn't mean you should edit the code.

Comment: ok, stylistic I get it, but what about unneeded else clause?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Again, that's purely a stylistic change.  You changed *nothing* about the code by removing the `else` clause other than changing how it looks.  It literally functions identically either way.

Comment: Also stylistic. Seriously, it's just an else. Leave it.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: Functionally, leaving out the `else` clause makes _no_ difference. It's a stylistic choice. Just as adding those brackets is. Edits are not meant to force your stylistic opinion on an answer, like that.

Comment: I get it i get it

Comment: Technically, there are 2 suggested edits... [The first one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13570587) was rejected by one reviewer, approved by 3. The second one is still pending (and should be rejected).

Comment: @Tunaki: The second one is rejected.

Comment: @Tunaki technically there are 3 suggested edits: The [first one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13570587) was accepted and rolled back by OP, the [second one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13571770) was accepted and rolled back by OP, and the [third one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13586863) got just rejected...

Comment: @Floern Sigh... good catch.

Comment: you edit was not *stylistic* [it actually reduced the correctness of the code in many ways and is a terrible practice regardless how many people think it is ok it is not correct because the actual behavior of your edit can be completely different than what it was.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946963/if-vs-else-if-vs-else-statements)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson When would the two different snippets ever function differently?  Care to provide an example?  Of course, if the body of the `if` didn't *always* return then that would be another matter entirely.  The edit is still inappropriate, being just a stylistic change, but it *is* just a stylistic change.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Well, you've clearly stated that you know it doesn't change the functionality.  A change to the code that doesn't affect the functionality in any way is *by definition* a stylistic change.  It's the only thing that it *could* be.  If you *didn't* think it was a stylistic change than what *did* you think it was?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou That *is* a stylistic change.  It's changing nothing about the code other than its style.  That makes it a stylistic change.  Also `{` isn't a double quote.